# Iterating through a JSON array gives me 0 everytime

Tags: node.js, express

I have a very basic express API and I am making a call from PostMan to the API endpoint.
When I try to print the JSON item, it just prints 0.

```
router.post('/create', async (req, res) => {
    data = await req.body
    console.log(data)
    for (var obj in data) {
        console.log(obj)
    }
});
```

The POST request I send, has the body of:

```
[
    {
        "seatID": 30,
        "passenger": {
            "name": "Mr. a Huffle Puff",
            "sex": "M",
            "age": 52,
            "email": "karafasfaa@gmail.com"
        }
    }
]
```

And the console logs,

```
[
  {
    seatID: 30,
    passenger: {
      name: 'Mr. a Huffle Puff',
      sex: 'M',
      age: 52,
      email: 'karafasfaa@gmail.com'
    }
  }
]
0
```

I don't understand why it's printing 0, when it should be printing the JSON object. I am making a POST request as raw JSON.

Comment: `data = await req.body` why is there an await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (var... in...)` should be used to iterate over an object, not an array.

see documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

what you can do instead:

```
data.forEach((payload) => console.log(payload));
```

Comment: That's "abusing" `map` - I guess you want `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

`for in` iterates over *keys*. The keys of an array `['a', 'b', 'c']` will be `0`, `1`, `2` (since you would do `array[2]` and get `'c'` for example).

Since you probably want to iterate over *values*, you can use `for of` instead:

```js
for (const obj of data) {
  console.log(obj)
}
```